# increasing the height of image keeping width constant

Tags: html, css

In responsive page layout, I want to increase the height of image keeping the width constant. 
When I change image width, it reflects but changing the height does not make difference.

So I added `100%` height to parent div `.content container`. But that also does not make any difference.

How can I increase the height here keeping width constant?

FIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/g83e8/

I have used container as below:

```
<div id="content1" class="content">

    <div class="container">  
        <div class="img-container1">

            <img src="http://placehold.it/931x754"  alt="..." class="img-responsive img-rounded">       
        </div>
        <div class="text-container">
            <p>TEST</p>                
        </div>
        <div class="another-container">
            <p>TEST</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

css:

```
.content > container {height: 100%;}

    .img-container1 { float:left; height:60% !important; width:50%}
```

Comment: See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-height-property

Set `#content1`s height(not percent) or `.content > container`

Comment: @maximkou: in that case, will it remain responsive for varying size device and screen?

Comment: Or change `.content > container` to `.content > .container`(you forgot `.` symbol before class)

Comment: @maximkou: thanks, but no luck with this change please see http://jsfiddle.net/g83e8/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To increase the height of the image only, you can use styling like this:

`<img src="http://placehold.it/931x754"  alt="..." class="img-responsive img-rounded" style="height: 100px">`

Using pixels instead of percentages allows you to more easily control the size, as the size is not inherited from the parent elements when using pixels.

Comment: I want to create responsive page. I guess using pixel will not help me to do this.

Comment: Have you tried styling both the parent div and the image itself using percentages? For example `<div class="img-container1">` together with `<img src="http://placehold.it/931x754"  alt="..." class="img-responsive img-rounded" style="height: 100%">` Perhaps with the combination of the two set heights, it will work dynamically.